# Is there an interface that enables > < and all the other comparison operators?

Tags: .net, vb.net, interface, operator-overloading, syntactic-sugar

I'm mucking about, making a generic class, and all this time I thought using types that implemented `IComparable` enabled using the comparison operators.

I know `.CompareTo()` can perform functionally the same operations, but I have a nagging feeling that there must be an interface that implements the comparison operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Operators cannot be specified via an interface.

> [Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x.aspx) define the properties, methods, and events [but not operators] that classes can implement.

The closest interface, as noted, is `IComparable`.

Some languages have more sugar mapping (e.g Scala) but not VB.NET or C#.

Comment: This deficit is particularly frustrating as the IComparable.CompareTo method doesn't have the same behaviour as the `<`, `>` and `==` operators for some edge cases, such as comparisons involving `Double.NaN`.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than by implementing an interface, this is accomplished through [operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379613%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  So, to overload the greater-than and less-than comparison operators, for instance, you could do something like this:

```
Public Class MyNumber
    Public Value As Integer

    Public Overloads Shared Operator >(ByVal x As MyNumber, ByVal y As MyNumber) As Boolean
        Return (x.Value > y.Value)
    End Operator

    Public Overloads Shared Operator <(ByVal x As MyNumber, ByVal y As MyNumber) As Boolean
        Return (x.Value < y.Value)
    End Operator
End Class
```

Since operator overloads are defined as `Shared`, they cannot be declared by an interface.  Interfaces in VB.NET can only declare instance-members.  They cannot declare shared members.

Comment: That's a good tip, but overloading the operators isn't a solution since I'm working with generics.  I didn't realize `static` / `Shared` functions can't be part of interfaces though, good to know.

Comment: @j.i.h. If that's the case, that's what the interfaces such as `IComparable` are for.  That's why they exist.  You just have go through the interface to perform the comparison operation, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't constrain generic types based on which operators they support.